# Cordova:the file of js-moudle changes when compile

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

When I created a cordova plugin,I met a question that the file of js-module was changing during the compile.

Below is a snapshot before and after the compile of a file that is changing.

**Before:**

```
cordova.define("cordova-plugin-mipush.MiPush", function(require, exports, module) {
     some code....
});
```

**After:**

```
cordova.define("cordova-plugin-mipush.MiPush", function(require, exports, module) {
cordova.define("cordova-plugin-mipush.MiPush", function(require, exports, module) {
     some code....
});
});
```

I tried to find the reason that causes it,but I failed.

Any ideas? leads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your putting in the above code manually when it should be done automatically by Corodva. In your plugin interface the only thing you need at a minimum is something like this:

```
var exec = require('cordova/exec');
function MiPus () {}; 
module.exports = new MiPus();
```

Cordova will take care of the rest and transform it once its added to a platform in your project. Results should look like this:

```
cordova.define("cordova-plugin-mipush.MiPush", function(require, exports, module) {

var exec = require('cordova/exec');
function MiPus () {}; 
module.exports = new MiPus();

});
```